# How to Multiply Multiple Cells with a Constant Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had a table in excel where prices of products are written in US Dollars. I want to change these cells to Euros and some markup so I had to multiply all these cells with a constant cell which contains something like this =0.86*1.03*1.15.

The problem is I had to keep initial US Dollar amount on the formula because I had to change this constant cell regularly due to currency and markup changes. So every time I change it, it has to multiply with the initial amount.

I tried to set multiply formula to each cell but there are too many to write it every cell the same formula. Is there any option to set a formula to apply all those cells where multiplies initial amount with the constant cell?

Answer (score 0):

So, you should do something like this, assuming the constant is in cell A1 and the prices in cells A5 onwards.

In cell B5 enter:

```
=$A$1*A5
```

and drag down as far as needed.

Edit, based on comments: if the values are in an existing table, then the calculations could be performed in a helper column then copy / pastevalues back over the original prices...

Comment: Actually, I don't want to break table form. I want to make chances on the cells.

Comment: It was difficult to understand that in your question, but, to take an existing value in a cell, calculate with it and then return it to the cell you need vba, so you should look into that. However you could do what i suggested in a helper column then copy / paste the results back in the table.